# DropDownCheckBoxes in EditItemTemplate

Tags: c#, asp.net, edititemtemplate

I want to use DropDownCheckBoxes control in EditItemTemplate of my TemplateField. When I put it in normal ItemTemplate - it works. But when DropDownCheckBoxes is in EditItemTemplate - it doesn't appears...
"Select" is the only word that appears in the place where should be my DDCB.

```
<asp:TemplateField>
     <ItemTemplate>
          <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblTest" Text='<%# Bind("test") %>' />
     </ItemTemplate>
     <EditItemTemplate>
         <asp:DropDownCheckBoxes ID="ddcbTest" runat="server"></asp:DropDownCheckBoxes>              
       </EditItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Have you ever tried to use DropDownCheckBoxes in EditItemTemplate?

Comment: How do you data bind it?

Comment: Post your code behind here.

Comment: @PiyushKhatri There is not code behind for my ddcb

Comment: @Andrei For test I created simply DropDownCheckBoxes without data... and it works everywhere except EditItemTemplate.